# NoMethodError: ruby gem mechanize undefined method 'q= '

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to build a webscraping program for Amazon, but I'm getting tripped up on the very first step. I wrote my code like this, to just start to poke around and access Amazon and prettypage so I know how to proceed:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.amazon.com/')

page_form = page.form('site-search')

page_form.q = 'Intermediate Microeconomics'

page = agent.submit(page_form, page_form.buttons.first)

pp page
```

and I keep getting this error message:

```
/Users/samsunknight/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mechanize-2.7.1/lib/mechanize/form.rb:217:in `method_missing': undefined method `q=' for #<Mechanize::Form:0x007f9a13012660> (NoMethodError)
        from webscraperattempt1.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I've adapted this code from the example for google.com, and it works seamlessly for `agent.get('www.google.com')` and `page.form('f')`, so I imagine that the problem lies in `page.form('site-search')`, but when I `pp page` for www.amazon.com, "site-search" appears in the exact same place as "f" does for google.

What am I doing wrong? / How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
 page_form['q'] = 'Intermediate Microeconomics'
```

Answer (score 0):

`q` is the name of the field on the google form. On the amazon form it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try change q with 'field-keywords' like this:
`page_form['field-keywords'] = 'Intermediate Microeconomics'`